# How to show only specific post in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm trying to use `Jekyll` for creating a simple single page web site. This website will further be used for creating posts like `content blocks`.

But in my `Jekyll` site I want only show certain posts and not all of those available.

How to can I get a certain specific post, without using `for` and `if` for filtering the posts? Is this possible?

---

Edit 1:

In order for me get any specific post, I am using following way:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
   {% if post.title = "my title" %}
      <h3> {% post.title %} </h3>
      blablabla
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So, has anyone found an easy way to display the specific post with "my title", without using `for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any post with `published: false` in his front mater will not appear in a `{% for post in site.posts %}` loop.

But I don't understand your idea to get rid of `for` and `if`

Comment: I update my question, maybe can clarify more by idea

Comment: Maybe I can use published: false property, because maybe I need post that post in other page.

Comment: Or you can explain a little more what you're trying to do.

Comment: So, maybe I'm trying using Jekyll like "WordPress", I want create a posts for using as static page, not using as blog, example: in my Home page, I want show 3 posts specifics, in page About, will show post about "About", etc

Comment: Why use post instead of pages ?

Comment: I don't know, I'm beginner in Jekyll, correct is create a "Page" for this, and not post?

Answer (score 0):

Just put `published: false` in your YAML front matter and run the loop without `if` statement in your code. Posts with `published: false` won't be displayed.